# Java Runtime exec command execution failing to correctly execute multi folder command

Tags: java, terminal

Using `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()`, i am trying to create multiple nested folders inside a folder by executing below command

```
mkdir -p /mypath/HumanResourse/PrivacyandSecurity/{Source,QA}
```

But, It is failing to create last nested folders `Source` and `QA` instead it is creating folder `{Source,QA}`.

How can i make sure that this command work?

Comment: Why are you providing folders to create nested as  `{Source,QA}`?

Comment: @Sohan Hmm. I can elaborate it, but i am using shortcut.

Comment: I don't think this will work. I have not seen such type of examples or usage